# Text alignment: extracting matching sequence using python

Tags: python, text, alignment, sequence

My goal is to extract the aligned matching sequence in two text passages. Next are my texts:

```
txt1='the heavy lorry crashed into the building at midnight'
txt2='what a heavy lorry it is that crashed into the building'
```

Expected output:

```
'heavy lorry'
'crashed into the building'
```

My attempt:

```
def sequ(s1,s2):
    _split1=s1.split()
    _split2=s2.split()
    _match=''.join(list(set(_split1) & set(_split2)))
    return _match

print sequ(txt1, txt2)

Result: heavybuildingintocrashedthelorry
```

......distorted result.

Any suggestions as to how to arrive at the expected result?
Thanks.

Comment: A set is an unordered container. While you're working on that, change your `_match` line to `' '.join(blah blah blah` - you'll get individual words that way

Comment: thanks for responding @MattDMo, it seems falsetru has solved the problem, but his approach might be a bit too long.

Comment: @Tiger1, You can compress the last 4 lines into one line using list comprehensioN: `return [' '.join(words1[block.a:block.a+block.size]) for block in matcher.get_matching_blocks() if block.size]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) does exactly what you want.

```
import difflib

def sequ(s1, s2):
    words1 = s1.split()
    words2 = s2.split()
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=words1, b=words2)
    for block in matcher.get_matching_blocks():
        if block.size == 0:
            continue
        yield ' '.join(words1[block.a:block.a+block.size])

txt1 = 'the heavy lorry crashed into the building at midnight'
txt2 = 'what a heavy lorry it is that crashed into the building'
print list(sequ(txt1, txt2))
```

output:

```
['heavy lorry', 'crashed into the building']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
txt1='the heavy lorry crashed into the building at midnight'
txt2='what a heavy lorry it is that crashed into the building'

s1, s2 = txt1.split(), txt2.split()
l1, l2 = len(s1), len(s2)
set1 = {" ".join(s1[j:j+i]) for i in range(1,l1+1) for j in range(l1+1-i)}
set2 = {" ".join(s2[j:j+i]) for i in range(1,l2+1) for j in range(l2+1-i)}
r = sorted(set1.intersection(set2), key = lambda x: len(x.split()))
rs = [j for k,j in enumerate(r) if all(j not in r[i] for i in range(k+1,len(r)))]
print rs
# ['heavy lorry', 'crashed into the building']
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @thefourtheye, your solution works but appears to be inline with dynamic programming which is computationally expensive.